# Expected number of tosses till first head comes up

Tags: probability, self-study, expected-value, bernoulli-distribution, geometric-distribution

Suppose that a fair coin is tossed repeatedly until a head is obtained for the first time.

- What is the expected number of tosses that will be required?
- What is the expected number of tails that will be obtained before the first head is obtained?

Comment: This link has the answers for both questions: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution

Comment: If this is a self-study question, please add the tag.

Answer (score 25):

This can be answered using the ***geometric*** distribution as follows:

The number of failures ***k - 1*** before the first success (heads) with a probability of success ***p*** ("heads") is given by:

$$p(X=k)=(1−p)^{k−1}p$$

with ***k*** being the total number of tosses including the first 'heads' that terminates the experiment.

And the expected value of ***X*** for a given ***p*** is $1/p=2$.

The derivation of the expected value can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/235927/where-am-i-going-wrong-with-this-proof-of-expected-value-of-a-geometric-random-v). The last steps left implicit should be as follows:

$\frac{d}{dr} \frac{1}{1-r} = \frac{1}{(1-r)^2}$ to be plugged into the expression:

$E(X) = \frac{p}{1-p} \sum\limits_{x = 1}^{\infty}x\ r^x = \frac{p}{1-p}\ r\ (\frac{d}{dr} \frac{1}{1-r})= \frac{p}{1-p}\ r\ \frac{1}{(1-r)^2}$. With $r = 1 - p$, it simplifies to

$E(X) = \frac{1}{p}$, justifying its use above.]

Alternatively, we could use the ***negative binomial*** distribution interpreted as the number of failures before the first success. The probability mass function is given as the *p(number of failures, **n***, before attaining **r** successes | given a certain probability, ***p***, of success in each Bernoulli trial):

$$p(n;r,p) ={n+r-1\choose r-1} p^r (1-p)^n$$

The expectation for number of trials, ***n + r*** is given by the general formula:

$$\frac{r}{(1-p)}$$

Given our known parameters: ***r = 1*** and ***p = 0.5***,

$$E(n + r; 1,0.5) =\frac{r}{1-p} = \frac{1}{1-0.5} = 2$$

Hence we can expect to make two tosses before getting the first head with the the expected number of tails being $E(n+r) - r = 1$.

We can run a Monte Carlo simulation to prove it:

```
   set.seed(1)

p <- 1/2

reps <- 10000                         # Total number of simulations.

tosses_to_HEAD <- 0                   # Setting up an empty vector to add output to.

for (i in 1:reps) {
  head <- 0                           # Set the variable 'head' to 0 with every loop.
  counter <- 0                        # Same forlocal variable 'counter'.
  while (head == 0) {
    head <- head + rbinom(1, 1, p)    # Toss a coin and add to 'head'
    counter <- counter + 1            # Add 1 to 'counter'
  }
  tosses_to_HEAD[i] <- counter        # Append number in counter after getting heads.
}

mean(tosses_to_HEAD)
[1] 2.0097
```

Comment: For the current question, the distribution is called the Geometric distribution $\mathcal{G}(p)$.

Comment: `And the expected value of` $X$ `for a given` $p$ `is` $1/p$ and how is one supposed to prove that?

Comment: There is a nice derivation on http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/235927/where-am-i-going-wrong-with-this-proof-of-expected-value-of-a-geometric-random-v But I can include the end of that derivation on my response.

Answer (score 5):

Model the game by [drawing a ticket out of a box.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/50/what-is-meant-by-a-random-variable/54894#54894)  There are two kinds of tickets.  On one is written "Stop, you tossed heads"; on the other is written "Continue, you tossed tails."  The expected number of additional tosses in the first case is $0$ while the expected number of additional tosses in the second case is $x$, say--we don't know it yet and have to figure it out.

Write these expectations on their respective tickets: these are the *values* of the tickets.

The three things we do know are:

1. The chance of drawing a "Stop" ticket (with value $0$) is $p$.
2. The chance of drawing a "Continue" ticket (with value $x$) is $1-p$.
3. The expectation of this single draw is, by definition, the sum of the probability-weighted values on all kinds of tickets:

   $$p\times 0 + (1-p)\times x = (1-p)x.$$

Let us interpret this number: it is the expected number of *additional* tosses that will be needed until a head appears.  Since draws of tickets correspond to coin tosses, adding in the one draw needed to obtain a ticket gives us the expected number of tosses--which is just $x$ itself.  Equating these two expressions,

$$x = 1 + (1-p)x.$$

**Solving for $x$ answers the first question.**  Since the number of tails is always one less than the number of draws, the expected number of tails also must be one less than the expected number of draws.  **Therefore $x-1$ answers the second question.**

---

**A second intuitively clear solution** can be obtained by contemplating a very long sequence of $n$ tosses.  How many games were played?  Answer: the number of heads (plus one more incomplete game if the sequence ends with a series of tails).  How many heads are expected?  Answer: $pn$. Call this number $h$. The [Weak Law of Large Numbers](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WeakLawofLargeNumbers.html) asserts that the *actual* number of heads is highly likely to be very close to $pn$ provided $n$ is sufficiently large.  Therefore the average game length $x$, given by some number between $n/h$ and $n/(h+1)$, will be arbitrarily close to $n/(pn)$, whence it must equal $x$ itself.

**This leads to an extremely efficient way to simulate the distribution of game lengths**.  Here is `R` code.  It records "heads" as true values in a boolean array and computes the tosses between successive true values.

```R
p <- 1/3                                           # Set the chance of heads
tosses <- runif(1e6) < p                           # Make a million tosses
sim <- diff(c(TRUE, which(tosses)))                # Compute game lengths
hist(sim, xlab="Game length", main="Distribution") # Graph their distribution
mean(sim)                                          # Report the average length
```

When I ran this code after setting the seed to $17$ (`set.seed(17)`), the output differed from $x$ by only a tiny amount.

Comment: Could you help me understand why the "x" of the drawing game and the "x" in the second equation represent the same thing? I have no idea how do you get the second equation. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Light The second equation is explained in the paragraph preceding it.

Comment: ♦ Thank u for ur reply. I've read the definition of x and the paragraph you said again and again, but I still don't understand. Let me say my understanding and pls help me know if I misunderstand sth. From my understanding, x is the "additional" expected number in the drawing tickets game, which is a different game from the original game, beacause the expectation(let me call it "E") of the coin game includes the first tossing. In my opinion, E should be "x + 1", but they're not the same thing. In the equation, you made the x and E the same thing that makes me confused. Thank u.

Answer (score 3):

Let X be the number of coin flips required until a head is obtained.
So, we need to calculate E(X) (i.e. expected value of X).

We can condition E(X) on whatever our first flip is.
Let E(X|H) denote the number of remaining coin flips given I got a head on the first flip.
Similarly, let E(X|T) denote the number of remaining coin flips given I got a tail on the first flip.

By first step conditioning, we have

$E(X) = \frac{1}{2} * (1 + E(X|H)) + \frac{1}{2} * (1 + E(X|T))$

Now, as $E(X|H)$ denoted the remaining flips after receiving head on the first, it will be equal to 0 as I don't need to flip after getting 1 head.

And, $E(X|T) = E(X)$, as we did not make any progress towards getting 1 head.

So, $E(X) = \frac{1}{2} * (1 + 0) + \frac{1}{2} * (1 + E(X))$

=>  $E(X) = 2$