# how do you show that the average number of periods is 1/(1-a)

Tags: self-study

we have that the probability of winning a game is b and if you win you keep playing until you loose. And it says that the average number of consecutives wins is $1/(1-b)$, suppose infinite periods.

Well what the way i was trying to solve this is using a geometric sum, because the answer looks a little bit like a geometric sum, but i need some help. 
As allways thank you very much.

Comment: Also see https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/136808/919.

Comment: Note that for self-study questions you should try to explicitly show [what you have tried and where you are stuck](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). That said, note that while the geometric sum *is* similar, it has *constant* coefficients on the $b^k$ terms. But for an average the coefficients should be *the variable you are averaging*, i.e. you should have terms of the form $kb^k$.

Comment: Sorry, how do i close this thread, i got the answer. thanks ;)